# Ping reply not getting to LAN machines but getting in Linux router Gateway

Tags: linux, routing, gateway

I have configured Ubuntu 12.04 as Gateway machine.its having two interfaces

```
 eth0 with ip  192.168.122.39(Static) and 

 eth1 connected to modem with ip address 192.168.2.3(through DHCP).
```

ip-forwarding is enabled in router box.

Client machine is configured as:

```
ip address 192.168.122.5 and gateway 192.168.122.39
```

Client machines can ping router box(192.168.122.39).but when pinged 8.8.8.8 reply is not reaching Client machines but in the tcpdump output on gateway i can see echo request for 8.8.8.8 but never echo reply.Is this because of 122.5 not forwarding request to 2.0 network.Can u please help me in fixing this.

edit:STEPS FOLLOWED

This machine is running as XEN HVM.

Router machine:two interfaces eth0:192.168.122.39(static ip)
eth1:192.168.2.3
on router

```
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE 

 iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT

 iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

ptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT

On the client machine

```
 ping 8.8.8.8
```

on the gateway tcpdump result

**tcpdump -v -i eth0**

**192.168.122.1 is the virtual bridge**

tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes

14:17:26.352383 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
192.168.122.1 > google-public-dns-a.google.com: ICMP echo request, id 1541, seq 8395, 
length 64

14:17:26.938156 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    192.168.122.1 > google-public-dns-a.google.com: ICMP echo request, id 1513, seq 10735, length 64

**tracepath 8.8.8.8. from Client machine:**

> tracepath 8.8.8.8
>
> 1:  192.168.122.39                                          0.046ms
>   pmtu 1500
>
> 1:  192.168.122.5                                            0.259ms
>
> 1:  192.168.122.5                                                   0.188ms
>
> 2:  no reply
>
> 3:  no reply

Comment: What is the source IP address of the echo request coming out of the gateway? If it's not `192.168.2.3`, that's your problem. NAT/masquerading is not set up correctly. The replies will never get back to the machine since only the gateway machine knows to send them there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your modem doesn't know how to reach 192.168.122.0/24 network.
You have to do NAT on your router or you have to tell your modem that 192.168.122.0/24 should be routed through 192.168.2.3.

For NAT try with these rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE   
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Restart your firewall to flush old rules.

Comment: Actually i am not able to ping 8.8.8.8.whenever i make a rqst to 8.8.8.8 in the tcpdump out of gateway machine i can see echo request but no reply.So doesnt that mean 122 network is not forwarding request to 2.0 network? can u help me please guide me :)

Comment: Your gateway forwards requests from 122. The problem is with replies. Your modem does not know where 192.168.122 network is. So if it got a reply from 8.8.8.8 when trying to sent it to 192.168.122 network it will forward it to its gateway and not to your gateway. If you can set a static route in your modem you could set it to route 192.168.122.0/24 network via 192.168.2.3.

Comment: I did this on router route add -net 192.168.122.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.2.3 dev eth1>but still the same.. :(

Comment: This route should be applied on modem, not on router. NAT is a solution too. But the last line has '-i eth1 -o eth1' which is not correct. I suggest you to remove this part or to correct it to -o eth0.

Comment: If NAT ing is an option,then why am i not able to ping public networks. Is anything wrong with the NATing...

Comment: Try with rules I put in my answer.

Comment: I am sorry to tell u that..it also didnt help.Client machines still can not ping public ip address.As i said these machines are all VMs.Does that has anything to do with this?

Comment: Can you ping public ip addresses from router? Can you post output of route -n from your router?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6086/discussion-between-kevin-parker-and-laurentiu-roescu)

Comment: Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth1
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

Comment: As i said..192.168.122.1 is a virtual brdige that makes vm in this network to communicate with other VM in the network.This setup worked when i tried this in real hardware.Dont know why this happened on VM.